# R-exams: Omit subquestions in exam, but include in solution

Tags: r, r-exams

I am currently looking into r-exam for generating PDF exams.
A single question consists of several subquestions, and is written in Rmd, as in the example below:

```
Question
========

Calculate the following:

Answerlist
----------

* 1+1
* 2+2

Solution
========

Answerlist
----------

* 2
* 4

Meta-information
================

extype: cloze
exclozetype: num|num
exsolution:  2|4
exname: test
```

The exam is then generated using `exams2pdf` (which combines several Rmd files).

Is there a way to only include the first subquestion (1+1) in the exam, but include both subquestions and their answers in the solution?

Might be a strange question, but this exam will be used as preparation for an oral exam. The first subquestion is with preparation (so therefore it should be included in the exam PDF). The second subquestion is without preparation (asked during oral exam), so it should not be in the exam PDF, but it would be handy if I could include these additional questions in the solution PDF somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If the subquestion are in the same cloze question, I don't see an easy how to do what you want. However, if you put them into separate exercises it's "relatively" straightforward via custom templates.

Say you have two items `item1.Rmd` (num with the 1+1 exercise) and `item2.Rmd` (num with the 2+2 exercise). Then you need three templates: `preparation.tex`, `oral.tex`, and `combined_solution.tex`. The first two generally hide the solution environment while the latter shows it. Additionally, the first two do not show all exercises while the latter does. More details are below and in Section 3 of `vignette("exams", package = "exams")`. Then you can do

```
`exams2pdf(c("item1.Rmd", "item2.Rmd"), n = 3,
  template = c("preparation.tex", "oral.tex", "combined_solution.tex"))
```

The `combined_solution.tex` template shows both question and solution and all exercises:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

...

\newenvironment{question}{\item \textbf{Problem}\newline}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{\textbf{Solution}\newline}{}

...

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
%% \exinput{exercises}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The `preparation.tex` only shows the first exercise (but not the second) and hides  the solution environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

...

\newenvironment{question}{\item \textbf{Problem}\newline}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{\comment}{\endcomment}

...

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\input{exercise1.tex}
\item \emph{Oral part.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Conversely, the `oral.tex` only shows the second exercise (but not the first) and hides  the solution environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

...

\newenvironment{question}{\item \textbf{Problem}\newline}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{\comment}{\endcomment}

...

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \emph{Preparation part.}
\input{exercise2.tex}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Instead of including `\item \emph{...}` for the hidden exercises you can also increase the counter or use nested `{enumerate}` environments or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion and example!

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it here on StackOverflow so that it gets flagged accordingly.